# Can kettle export BLOB data from a oracle table?

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have a oracle table where I have columns like Document (type BLOB), Extension ( VARCHAR2(10) with values like .pdf, .doc) and Document Description(VARCHAR2
(100)). I want to export this data and provide to my customer.

Can this be done in kettle ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a MSSQL database that stores images in a BLOB column, and found a way to export these to disk using a dynamic SQL step.

First, select only the columns necessary to build a file name and SQL statement (id, username, record date, etc.).  Then, I use a `Modified Javascript Value` step to create both the output filename (minus the file extension):

```
outputPath = '/var/output/';
var filename = outputPath + username + '_' + record_date;
// --> '/var/output/joe_20181121'
```

and the dynamic SQL statement:

```
var blob_query = "SELECT blob_column FROM dbo.table WHERE id = '" + id + "'";
```

Then, after using a select to reduce the field count to just the filename and blob_query, I use a `Dynamic SQL row` step (with "Outer Join" selected) to retrieve the blob from the database.

The last step is to output to a file using `Text file output` step.  It allows you to supply a file name from a field and give it a file extension to append.  On the Content tab, all boxes are unchecked, the Format is "no new-line term" and the Compression is "None".  The only field exported is the "blob_column" returned from the dynamic SQL step, and the type should be "binary".

Obviously, this is MUCH slower than other table/SQL operations due to the dynamic SQL step making individual database connections for each row... *but it works.*

Good luck!